# Rails display name attribute from different table along with count from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following tables: Products, Categories, ProductCategory.

I'm trying to display in a branch structure something like:

```
Accessories - 5,000
 Men's Watches - 2,000
  Tag Huer - 1,000
  Samsung - 1,000
 Women's Watches - 3,000
```

The issue I'm getting into is that my query is slowing down the application. I have the following query:

```
def category_level
 Connector::Category.includes(:products).group_by(&:parent_category_id)
end
```

Then in my views I have the following:

```
<ul class="list-style-upper">
 <% category_level[nil].each do |root| %>
  <%= render 'products/submenu/category_item', category: root %>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

Which loads into:

```
<li class="list-one">
 <a href="#"><%= category.name %><p><%= category.products.count %></p></a>
 <% if category_level[category.id].present? %>
  <ul class="list-style-upper-sub">
    <% category_level[category.id].each do |child| %>
      <%= render 'products/submenu/category_item', category: child %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
 <% end %>
</li>
```

It displays but takes a long time due to it hitting the Products table and looping through all the products. So to make it easier I thought I'd just hit the ProductCategory page to get a count with the following:

```
def level_up
 @category_counts = Connector::ProductCategory.group(:category_id).count
end
```

This will actually just display the following:

```
{54 => 11, 29 => 14, 51 => 19, 10 => 3202}
```

Although yes 10 would represent Accessories I'd rather see Accessories - 3,202.

Any advice on cleaning this up to pull in the attribute of name?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your models look something like:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
end

class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
end
```

You can get a count of the associated items by joining and selecting a count of the joined table:

```
Category.left_outer_joins(:product_categories)
  .select('categories.*, count(product_categories.*) AS product_count')
  .group('categories.id')
```

[`.left_outer_joins`](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html) was added in Rails 5. For earlier versions use:

```
.join('LEFT OUTER JOIN product_categories ON product_categories.category_id = category.id')
```

You can also use `.joins(:product_categories)` if you don't care about categories without any products.

The count will be available as `.product_count` on each record.

This can also be achieved by adding a counter cache:

```
class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category, counter_cache: true
end

class AddProductCategoriesCountToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :categories, :product_categories_count, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

This will store a count in `categories.product_categories_count`. Counter caches are best used when you have more read than write operations.

Comment: So I tried in my view: <%=level_up.product_count%>. Ended up with Can't join 'Connector::Category' to association named 'connector_product_categories'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Its hard to really help you further without knowing what your model setup actually is. This answer shows a generic way to get the count of a joined table - you have to actually try to understand and adapt the code.